# Mysql Group by showing multiple rows

Tags: mysql

Database structure

Table 'Org_f_a_list'

```
  id    org_id    user_id    date_added
  1          1          1      2017-01-01 05:05:05
```

Table 'Users'

```
  id      username      last_login
   1      Testuser     2017-01-01 05:05:05
```

Table 'Users_pa'

```
  id      user_id        summoner_id       rank_solo
   1            1                  1               15
   2            1                  2               17
```

My current query

```
select max(rank_solo) as rank,last_login,username,o.user_id,date_added 
      from org_f_a_list o
      join users u on o.user_id = u.id 
      join users_pa as p on u.id = p.user_id
      where org_id = :org 
      group by u.id,rank_solo,date_added
      order by rank desc
```

What I want the result to be

```
 user_id      user_name     rank    date_added    last_login
       1      Testuser       17           date          date
```

My current result

```
   user_id     user_name    rank      date_added    last_login
         1     Testuser       15            date          date
         1     Testuser       17            date          date
```

For some reason the group by u.id is not doing anything and I still pull both rows and not just the max rank

Edit : That fixed it. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

remove `rank_solo` from group by

```
select max(rank_solo) as rank,last_login,username,o.user_id,date_added 
from org_f_a_list o
join users u on o.user_id = u.id 
join users_pa as p on u.id = p.user_id
where org_id = :org 
group by u.id,date_added
order by rank desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Rank Should not be part of group by  as it is causing forming of two different groups

Answer (score 0):

You can Remove the Rank_solo from the Group By Like this:

```
  select max(rank_solo) as rank,last_login,username,o.user_id,date_added 
  from org_f_a_list o
  join users u on o.user_id = u.id 
  join users_pa as p on u.id = p.user_id
  where org_id = :org 
  group by u.id,date_added
  order by rank desc
```

You can Use Having with the same Query

```
  select max(rank_solo) as rank,last_login,username,o.user_id,date_added 
  from org_f_a_list o
  join users u on o.user_id = u.id 
  join users_pa as p on u.id = p.user_id
  where org_id = :org 
  group by u.id,date_added
  Having rank_solo = max(ranl_solo)
  order by rank desc
```